# Simulating a for loop in haskell

Tags: haskell, for-loop

I am currently writing my bachelor CS thesis for my studies in Austria.

The programming language that I use is Haskell.

Now, I am trying to find a way to fix my following issue:
I have a list of tuples, lets say `[(1,2),(2,3)]`. From that list of tuples, I would now like to pick out each of that tuples and then do an operation on it:
`Map.insert (1,2) XXX ftable`
where 
`(1,2)` is the first element of that list and `XXX` is some value and `ftable` is my map.

How can I "iterate" through that list and proceed with that operation inserting the "n-th" elment of my list to my map?

I guess I am just too much familiar with programming imperative and I do not find a way to fix that in Haskell.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. A fold? `foldl' insertIt map tuples`?

Comment: Haskell does not simulate for loops. For loops simulate Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear what you mean here. Is it correct to assume that the tuples are meant to represent the keys in your map and XXX is some value attached to a specific key? Are all the values you want to match to a given key also provided in a list? In that case you can easily use the `fromList` function in `Data.Map`:

```
keys = [(1,2),(2,3),(7,9)]
values = ["A","B","C"]

map = Data.Map.fromList $ zip keys values
```

Answer (score 3):

Think about what your loop is doing.

- if it transforms each list element, then use `map` (or `concatMap`)
- if it filters out some of the list elements, then use `filter`
- if it reduces the list to a summary value, use a fold (e.g. `foldl`, `foldr`; more specific folds are `sum`, `and`, etc)
- or if it's doing some combination of the above, use a combination of the above functions

In your case, I'm not entirely certain what you want, but I think you want to end up with a single `Map`, so you want to fold your list. Perhaps something like

```
foldl (\oldMap key -> Map.insert key xxx oldMap) ftable yourListOfTuples
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to iterate on lists, each one to be chosen depending on the effect you're searching for:

- [folds](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold), they are useful for many computations on lists. They may also be what you're looking for, but I do not understand from your question your specific issue.
- [map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amap), that applies the same (given) function on every element of the input list returning the list of the results. There are also [variants that works in monadic computations](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3amapM).
- or, if it best suits your needs, you can always write your own [tail recursive](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tail_recursion) function: haskell will treat them just like for loops, without consuming heap (but please look at the reference link for a good explanation of the technique).

In the end, whatever function or technique you will use, it will be based on recursion since functional languages like Haskell do not admit for-loops in the form you are used to.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of hakoja's suggestion...

It is probable that XXX at this point is either 1) constant for every key, or 2) some function based on the key, or 3) somehow defined in parallel to the key.

1) constant xxx for every key

```
keys = [(1,2),(2,3),(7,9)]
xxx = "A"

ftable = Data.Map.fromList $ zip keys (repeat xxx)
```

2) function produces value based on key

```
keys = [(1,2),(2,3),(7,9)]
f = ...

ftable = Data.Map.fromList $ zip keys (map f keys)
```

3) xxx defined in parallel: use hakoja's suggestion